# How do I trace code involving loops and lists?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am just confused on how this program opperates and how I would trace it to solve the questions. The answers are 9, 16, 16, and 33.

> Consider the following code segment. Recall that % is the remainder operator when it is applied to two
>   integers.

```
    values = [2,4,8,16,32]
    for i in range(0,3):
     values[i] = values[i+2]
    for i in range(0,len(values)):
     if i % 2 == 0:
     values[i] = values[i] + 1
    print(values)
```

27. At the end of this code segment, values[0] has the value: _________________________________
28. At the end of this code segment, values[1] has the value: _________________________________
29. At the end of this code segment, values[3] has the value: _________________________________
30. At the end of this code segment, values[4] has the value: _________________________________

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Why not sprinkle the code with `print()` calls and see for yourself?

Comment: Which part specifically are you confused about? You seem to understand there's loops and lists involved, so you've at least learned that much... Write each step of the program down by hand

Comment: I am confused on why it says print(values). Like does that mean print(values[i])?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Insert useful output statements to trace the control and data flow.

Comment: Well, what does `print(values)` do?  Post the output you got, and explain where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a test question you are asking for help with.

Honestly, just track the code through each iteration of the for loops to solve these questions. It can be quite helpful to write it down when working on it.

Comment: You can add this as the comment instead of an answer!